# creating a relationship in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have the table "Ubicaciones" tag has a column "ubicacion" with unique values
[image: table ubicaciones]

But when I try to create the relationship between Ubicaciones and Proyectos I get this message
[image: error]

I think that is caused by the first empty record in Ubicaciones table but the All function always put this empty record an I don´t know how eliminate it.

Any idea please??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Without a more detailed look at both columns it's difficult to tell.

You should

- filter out all empty rows after applying the All-function and see if this solves the problem

  - check the table you want to link to for any empty rows, errors or duplicate values (this also applies to stuff like "ABCDE" and "Abcde" which is regarded as the same value sometimes)

Comment: The ALL Function give me all the diferente values of the three columns indicated but always add an empty record and I don´t know how to filter that empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure to Create Relationship on power bi

Step1: Go to modeling and select manage Relationship option

[image]

Step2: Select the new relationship option

[image]

Step3: Select table from and to, then select the field to join ex. id

[image]

Step4: Once you selected the relationship `( 1:1 / 1:* / *:1 / *:* )` then it creates the link between tables

[image]